# Changing current mail merge to use new source data

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, mail-merge

I have a mail merge file that I created last year, I would like to use a new source data file to create new post cards. 
Can this be done and how do I go about doing it?  I really don't want to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Word document containing the Mail Merge. Perform the following:

- Go to the Mailings tab in the ribbon
- Select Recipients
- Select "Use Existing List..."
- Select your new data source